# Multiple power banks to handle temporary increase in power demand

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, poe, powerbanks

I have 1 PoE+ (Power over Ethernet) port from which I need to power 5 Raspberry Pi 4s.
The recommended power supply for Raspberry Pi 4 is 5.1 V / 3 A which gives 15.3 so 5 Pis will require up to 76.5 W which is far more than 25.5 W I can get from PoE+ port.

The Raspberry Pis will be under load for maximum several hours a day such that daily energy draw will not exceed what PoE+ can supply. I thought that I could use pass through power banks to fix my issue.

I would like to thus use this setup:

**EDIT**: redesign - current limiter + new design

Power bank in parallel:

```
PoE+    +--------------+       +---------+
------->| PoE Splitter |------>| USB hub |
        +--------------+       +---------+
                                | | | | |
                     +-----------------------------+
                     | Current limiter.            |
                     | May be part of the USB hub. |
                     +-----------------------------+
                       |   |        |         |  |
            +----------+   |        |         |  +-----------+
            |              |        |         |              |
            |              |        |         |              |
            v              v        v         v              v
+------------+ +------------+ +------------+ +------------+ +------------+
| Power Bank | | Power Bank | | Power Bank | | Power Bank | | Power Bank |
+------------+ +------------+ +------------+ +------------+ +------------+
      |              |              |              |              |      
      v              v              v              v              v      
+-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+
| Raspberry |  | Raspberry |  | Raspberry |  | Raspberry |  | Raspberry |
| Pi 4      |  | Pi 4      |  | Pi 4      |  | Pi 4      |  | Pi 4      |
+-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+
```

Power banks in series:

```
PoE+    +--------------+       
------->| PoE Splitter |
        +--------------+      
          |                            
          v 
    +-------+      +-------+      +-------+      +-------+      +-------+
    | Power |----->| Power |----->| Power |----->| Power |----->| Power |
    | bank  |      | bank  |      | bank  |      | bank  |      | bank  |
    +-------+      +-------+      +-------+      +-------+      +-------+
        |              |              |              |              |
        v              v              v              v              v
+-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+
| Raspberry |  | Raspberry |  | Raspberry |  | Raspberry |  | Raspberry |
| Pi 4      |  | Pi 4      |  | Pi 4      |  | Pi 4      |  | Pi 4      |
+-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+
```

Before I spend money on all the power banks - is there a reason this setup will not work?

Comment: You cannot guarantee problem free with load regulated voltages without accurate calculations of cables and actual peak currents. and ground shift noise. Don't you want to verify your loss budget? and EMI crosstalk?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thank you. I wouldn't know how to calculate these things correctly and might not actually have all the details at hand. In any case, if this setup is not obviously broken then I'm willing to try it out. Thank you again.

Comment: How will you ensure your power banks won't each draw more than 5.1 W (minus any losses in the hub)? The 3 A pi consumption is a maximum. You can measure the actual consumption in your configuration.

Comment: can you get cable length gauge, resistance and use ohm's law? show layout and distance , maybe use 1 supply shared on coaxial ports

Comment: In theory, you might be able to find a USB hub that limits draw on each of its ports to 1A x 5 and let the built-in power negotiation between the power banks and the hub ensure that you don't go over 25.5W.  You'd probably want to do some testing since fuses are commonly used in power sourcing equipment and inadvertent overloading could buy you into some fiddly SMD replacement.

Comment: @Graham, vir Thank you. That would be a critical issue. Could I just connect them in series assuming each has an output ports?

Comment: Probably easier to find a 5-port hub with 1A output on each port.  I'd connect multiple in parallel if it came to that.

Comment: @ffffffffffjhtyjui Just connecting power banks in series won't guarantee a specific power consumption and it would mean each r.pi had a different ground reference. That would be awkward if they need to share connections. You would need to find power banks that specify the maximum charging power they take. Usually they just tell you their maximum output current.